# Obtener valor de combobox y usarlo en una consulta mysql como parametro

Tags: mysql, c#, combobox, parametros, picturebox

Tengo una situación que no puedo resolver, ya he buscado información en muchos lados y no consigo dar con la solución, son 3 cosas, pero no consigo ni resolver la primera, el problema es este:

1. Tengo una tabla en mi base de datos que contiene los campos `id`, `nombre` y `ruta_imagen`.
2. Tengo un `Combobox` que se llena con todos los registros del campo nombre a través de una consulta mysql
3. Tengo un `Picturebox` que quiero llenar con el valor de `ruta_imagen` del mismo registro que yo seleccione del `Combobox`, es decir, mi tabla esta asi:

> id=1, nombre=ballena, ruta_imagen= C:\win\user\carpeta\nom.jpg

Quiero que cuando yo seleccione `ballena`, la consulta me devuelva la `ruta_imagen` en el `Picturebox` y se muestre.

En el código que tengo, si lo hago pero de forma estática porque no logro hacerlo de la forma que quiero, ojala alguien pueda ayudarme.

código:

```
private void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost; User id=user; Database=mybase; Password=pass");
    string query = "select ruta_imagen from mytabla where id = 1";
    MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.ToInt32(comboBox3.SelectedIndex));
    con.Open();
    string rut = Convert.ToString(com.ExecuteScalar());
    MySqlDataReader show = com.ExecuteReader();

    while (show.Read())
    {
         pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile(rut);
    }
    con.Close();
    //dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Comment: Para empezar,tu query no está usando el parámetro, sino que siempre obtiene el id 1. Por otro lado, para que haces un `ExecuteReader`? No es necesario. Has comprobado que devuelve la consulta?

Comment: si asi es,  no ocupa parametro porque no se como hacerlo, lo hice asi para ver si lograba hacer lo que me proponia y vi que si lo hacia, que era mostrar la imagen, pero quiero hacerlo con parametro para que se haga al seleccionar del combobox, solo que no se como hacerlo pero deje el codigo para ejemplificar como buscaba hacerlo, y hacia la lectura porque lo he hecho asi en otras cosas, esta mal ??

Comment: Si te refieres a añadir el parametro en la consulta,esta sería `select ruta_imagen from mytabla where id = @id`. Ten en cuenta que estás pasándole el indice del combobox,y este empieza en 0. Tal vez debas sumarle 1 para que coincida con el id de la base de datos

Comment: pero entonces como le haria para que cuando me devuelva ese valor lo pueda mandar a mi picturebox, no necesito hacer el executereader??

Comment: Con el `ExecuteScalar`que tienes debería ser suficiente